# Revisiting questions closed as off-topic

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopening

I am going over old questions which are [closed](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=closed%3a1) as off-topic.

If you notice a question that is closed as off-topic (based on cstheory's scope at that time) which you think should be reopened (based on cstheory's *current* scope) please post a link to it below as an answer so we can revisit the decision.

Comment: Our scope has changed?

Comment: @Raphael, not recently, but over time yes, e.g. it was not clear at the start that Theory B is inside cstheory scope. Also note that it was much easier to close questions in the private and public beta phases.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a quick glance over all questions in the list with at least 2 up-votes. Maybe the only question with a positive change to be reopened is this:

> [Is Witten's new method of quantization useful for geometric complexity theory?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1881/1800)

And discussions with controversial opinions are already there in the comments.

Edit: As Kaveh said in the comments, this question is closed as not a real question, not as off-topic. So I don't see any question with at least 2 up-votes need to be revisited. Go for the rest soon.

Comment: Hsien-Chih Chang, thanks, but it is not closed as *off-topic*. (Also note that there is another policy against discussions about unpublished work which is not peer-reviewed.)

Comment: @Kaveh: Maybe I took the glance *too* quick. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, thanks for checking. :)